# Countable Additivity of Inner Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given that outer measure, defined as $$|A| = \inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k): I_1, I_2, \ldots \text{where every } I_k \text{ is an open interval s.t. }A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right\},$$ fails to be countably additive for a sequence of disjoint sets within the powerset of $\mathbf{R}$, how do you show inner measure, defined as $$\sup\left\{|F| : F \text{ is a closed bounded subset of }\mathbf{R} \text{ and } F \subset A \right\},$$ fails to be countably additive for a sequence of disjoint sets with the powerset of $\mathbf{R}$?